# How to keep vectors in a dictionary in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

It seems that `tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable` cannot hold vectors and I could not find examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a simple implementation of dictionary of vectors in Tensorflow. It is also an example of usage of `tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable` and `tf.TensorArray`.

As said, vectors cannot be kept in `tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable`, and therefore `tf.TensorArray` is used to keep the actual vectors.

Of course, this is a simple example, and it does not include deletion of entries in the dictionary - an operation that will require some management of the free cells of the array. Also, you should read in the respective API pages of `tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable` and `tf.TensorArray` how to tune them for your needs.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class DictionaryOfVectors:

  def __init__(self, dtype):
    empty_key = tf.constant('')
    deleted_key = tf.constant('deleted')

    self.ht = tf.lookup.experimental.DenseHashTable(key_dtype=tf.string,
                                                    value_dtype=tf.int32,
                                                    default_value=-1,
                                                    empty_key=empty_key,
                                                    deleted_key=deleted_key)
    self.ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False)
    self.inserts_counter = 0

  @tf.function
  def insertOrAssign(self, key, vec):
    # Insert the vector to the TensorArray. The write() method returns a new
    # TensorArray object with flow that ensures the write occurs. It should be 
    # used for subsequent operations.
    with tf.init_scope():
      self.ta = self.ta.write(self.inserts_counter, vec)

      # Insert the same counter value to the hash table
      self.ht.insert_or_assign(key, self.inserts_counter)
      self.inserts_counter += 1

  @tf.function
  def lookup(self, key):
    with tf.init_scope():
      index = self.ht.lookup(key)
      return self.ta.read(index)

dictionary_of_vectors = DictionaryOfVectors(dtype=tf.float32)
dictionary_of_vectors.insertOrAssign('first', [1,2,3,4,5])
print(dictionary_of_vectors.lookup('first'))
```

The example is a bit more sophisticated, as the insert and lookup methods are decorated with  `@tf.function`. Because the methods change variables defined outside of them, the `tf.init_scope()` is used. You might ask what is changed in the `lookup()` method as it actually only reads from the hash table and the array. The reason is that in graph mode, the index that is returned from the `lookup()` call is a Tensor, and in the TensorArray implementation there is a line containing `if index < 0:` which fails with:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.

When we use the `tf.init_scope()`, as explained in its API documentation, "code inside an init_scope block runs with eager execution enabled even when tracing a `tf.function`". So in that case that index is not a Tensor but as scalar.